# Android MediaPlayer Error (1,-22)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Error (1,-22) occurs after long playing (about hour or more) the same track in a loop. I can't figure out the reason of that error. Everything is okay if track is playing for short time. But if I keep track playing for long time in my `Service`, sometimes the error happens.

I know that 1 is `MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN`, but cant find anything about -22.

Any suggestions? API 24

Comment: Show the code that takes care of playing the track, and the exception generated if any?

Comment: @FiN it seems about another case; my error code is 1, not -22

Comment: @konopko Error is (1,-22).
Following  [developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) documentation, the 1 is `what` and -22 is `extra`.
P.S. Are you testing on emulator or on real device?

Comment: @FiN it seems your link contains `what` codes, but I need `extra` codes

Comment: What is your API level?

Comment: @FiN my API level is 24

Comment: Try implementing release of `mediaplayer` in `onCompletion()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to issue appears because I didn't call `MediaPlayer.release()` when `onCompletion` callback. As a result resources of MP did not released and finally MP crashed with the error.